Extracting audio frames using miniaudio.h
i am trying to make a simple audio fft visualizer, but i don't know much about audio programming.
Can somemone instruct me how could i extract a pcm frame with miniaudio.h library. I've seen some code from github and the famous streamer tsoding , but none of them use miniaudio.h directly for the thing i need.
I tried something like this:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <complex.h>
#define MINIAUDIO_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "miniaudio.h"

typedef struct {
    float left;
    float right;
} Frame;


#define N (1<<13)

float in[N];
float complex out[N];


void data_callback(ma_device* pDevice, void* pOutput, const void* pInput, ma_uint32 frameCount)
{
    ma_decoder* pDecoder = (ma_decoder*)pDevice->pUserData;
    /* if (pDecoder == NULL) { */
    /*     return; */
    /* } */
    Frame *fs = pOutput;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < frameCount; ++i) {
        memmove(in, in + 1, (N - 1)*sizeof(in[0]));
        in[N-1] = fs[i].left;
        fprintf(stderr,"%d  ",in[i]);
    }
    fprintf(stderr,"\n");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    ma_sound sound;
    ma_device_config deviceConfig;
    ma_device device;
    ma_result result;
    ma_decoder decoder;
    ma_engine engine;

    deviceConfig = ma_device_config_init(ma_device_type_playback);
    deviceConfig.playback.format   = ma_format_f32;
    deviceConfig.playback.channels = 2; // Stereo
    deviceConfig.sampleRate        = 44100;
    deviceConfig.dataCallback      = data_callback;
    result = ma_device_init(NULL, &deviceConfig, &device);
    if (result != MA_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Failed to initialize playback device.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    result = ma_device_start(&device);
    if (result != MA_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Failed to start playback device.\n");
        ma_device_uninit(&device);
        return -1;
    }

    //deviceConfig.pUserData =
    ma_engine_config engineConfig;


    engineConfig = ma_engine_config_init();
    /* engineConfig.pResourceManager = &myCustomResourceManager;   // <-- Initialized as some earlier stage. */
    result = ma_engine_init(&engineConfig, &engine);

    result = ma_decoder_init_file(argv[1], NULL, &decoder);
    if (result != MA_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ybg\n");
        return false;   // An error occurred.
    }
    result = ma_sound_init_from_file(&engine, argv[1], MA_SOUND_FLAG_DECODE, NULL, NULL, &sound);

    ma_sound_start(&sound);
    while(1){
    }

    ma_device_stop(&device);
    ma_device_uninit(&device);
    ma_sound_uninit(&sound);
}

and tried in a few more ways, including one from https://github.com/RoboBachelor/Music-Visualizer-Piano/blob/master/miniaudio.h, and as i understand it, i should get the current pcm frame with data_callback function.
Does anyone have idea how could i accomplish this?

Hello. Your question is a programming question, this is not the right place to ask for it. You should try to ask it on https://stackoverflow.com/questions, you might find more help there.
